# Neccessary and sufficient conditions to form a topological ring on $\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, topological-rings

Let $B = \{ \{a + b f_i(n) : n\in \Bbb{Z}\} : a,(b\neq 0) \in \Bbb{Z}, f_i \in F \}$.  Then what are necessary and sufficient conditions on the set of integer functions $F$ such that $B$ is a basis for a topological ring on $\Bbb{Z}$?  Let me know also if there's a better way of *setting all this up*.  Thanks.